# SQL Query to get particular output

Tags: sql, join

I have table like below:

| ID | COMPANY | DEPT | FLAG | INDICATOR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | HR | F | 2 |
| 1 | A | HR | P | 3 |
| 1 | A | HR | M | 4 |
| 1 | A | HR | F | 5 |
| 1 | A | HR | P | 6 |
| 1 | A | HR | M | 7 |

My output will be like this:

| ID | COMPANY | DEPT | FLAG | INDICATOR | C1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | HR | F | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | A | HR | P | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | A | HR | M | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | A | HR | F | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | A | HR | P | 6 | 5 |
| 1 | A | HR | M | 7 | 5 |

Can you please help me with the SQL query? I have tried to write query in Databricks SQL, but not getting this output.

The logic here is to calculate column C1, whenever the flag is F for a particular ID, COMPANY, DEPT combination, the corresponding indicator will be set as column C1 value; and it will be same till it encounters next F.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL [Window function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/) to get the result you wants in 2 steps.

1. Use window function to mark bucket_number along the way, increase it by +1 whenever we reach a 'F' flag
2. Use window fuction to set min indicator within bucket as C1

Here is the [query for step 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4e8f6/9):

```
select
    *,
    sum(case when FLAG = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by ID, COMPANY, DEPT order by INDICATOR) as bucket_number
from
    data_table
    order by ID, COMPANY, DEPT,INDICATOR
```

| ID | COMPANY | DEPT | FLAG | INDICATOR | bucket_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | HR | F | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | A | HR | P | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | A | HR | M | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | A | HR | F | 5 | 2 |
| 1 | A | HR | P | 6 | 2 |
| 1 | A | HR | M | 7 | 2 |

Here is the [query for all steps](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4e8f6/10):

```
with data_with_bukcet AS (
select
    *,
    sum(case when FLAG = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by ID, COMPANY, DEPT order by INDICATOR) as bucket_number
from
    data_table
)
select
    ID,
    COMPANY,
    DEPT,
    FLAG,
    INDICATOR,
    min(indicator) over (partition by ID, COMPANY, DEPT, bucket_number) as C1
from
    data_with_bukcet
order by ID, COMPANY, DEPT,INDICATOR
```

| ID | COMPANY | DEPT | FLAG | INDICATOR | C1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | HR | F | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | A | HR | P | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | A | HR | M | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | A | HR | F | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | A | HR | P | 6 | 5 |
| 1 | A | HR | M | 7 | 5 |

The above query works for both single (ID, COMPANY, DEPT) and mutiple (ID, COMPANY, DEPT) combinations.

Here is the [test result on mutiple (ID, COMPANY, DEPT) for step 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/61d16a/2):

| ID | COMPANY | DEPT | FLAG | INDICATOR | bucket_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | HR | F | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | A | HR | P | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | A | HR | M | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | A | HR | F | 5 | 2 |
| 1 | A | HR | P | 6 | 2 |
| 1 | A | HR | M | 7 | 2 |
| 2 | B | HR | F | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | B | HR | P | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | B | HR | M | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | B | HR | F | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | B | HR | P | 6 | 2 |
| 2 | B | HR | M | 7 | 2 |
| 3 | C | HR | F | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | C | HR | P | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | C | HR | M | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | C | HR | F | 5 | 2 |
| 3 | C | HR | P | 6 | 2 |
| 3 | C | HR | M | 7 | 2 |

Here is the [test result on mutiple (ID, COMPANY, DEPT) for all steps](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/61d16a/1):

| ID | COMPANY | DEPT | FLAG | INDICATOR | C1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | HR | F | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | A | HR | P | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | A | HR | M | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | A | HR | F | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | A | HR | P | 6 | 5 |
| 1 | A | HR | M | 7 | 5 |
| 2 | B | HR | F | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | B | HR | P | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | B | HR | M | 4 | 2 |
| 2 | B | HR | F | 5 | 5 |
| 2 | B | HR | P | 6 | 5 |
| 2 | B | HR | M | 7 | 5 |
| 3 | C | HR | F | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | C | HR | P | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | C | HR | M | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | C | HR | F | 5 | 5 |
| 3 | C | HR | P | 6 | 5 |
| 3 | C | HR | M | 7 | 5 |

Comment: thank you very much for answering this. But I have one doubt; Like for different partition key combination of ID, COMPANY, DEPT  if the INDICATOR  column again starts from 2 onwards like 2,3,4,5 for every rows; will this above solution work in that case? I'm facing some challenges in that scenario

Comment: Hi @mainak09, to clarify, you mean for the SAME (ID, COMPANY, DEPT), the INDICATOR will start from 2 again after reaching 5? or you mean for different (ID, COMPANY, DEPT),the INDICATOR column might have the same value 2.  for the latter case, the answer should have covered it as it is paritioned by (ID, COMPANY, DEPT) in the first call. Maybe you can descrbie a bit further on what you expect on same and different  (ID, COMPANY, DEPT) case.

Comment: Hi @jonathan200 thanks for your response. I was talking about the latter case, wherein we will have different (ID, COMPANY, DEPT), but the INDICATOR column again have same values like 2,3,4,5. And yes, I agree with you this scenario is covered in the partition by clause, but still wondering why it is not working for different combination of (ID, COMPANY, DEPT)!!!! the bucket _number are coming up from the 1st cte as 1.0.0.1....; which should be like 1,1,1,2....

Comment: Hi @mainak09, if the bucket_number is 1, 0, 0, 1, instead of 1,1,1,2, it is likely those rows are in fact in different (ID, COMPANY, DEPT) combination. Are you sure the first 3 rows of your output are in the same combination of (ID, COMPANY, DEPT)? I add an section to my answer to show and confirmation an run with correct results on 3 (ID, COMPANY, DEPT) combinations. both bucket number and C1 value are calculated correctly in both cases.  I also add order by clause at the end for your troubleshooting purpose so records with different (ID, COMPANY, DEPT) combination will display seperately.

Comment: Hi @mainak09, maybe you can describe what you will expect in the output when the first 3 rows are in different (ID, COMPANY, DEPT)  combinations.

Comment: thanks for answering in detail. I troubleshooted this. It works now.. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We can also use Window function with LAST to get latest value for FLAG - 'F'

I used below input

```
+---+-------+----+----+---------+
|ID |COMPANY|DEPT|FLAG|INDICATOR|
+---+-------+----+----+---------+
|1  |A      |HR  |F   |3        |
|1  |A      |HR  |P   |2        |
|1  |A      |HR  |M   |4        |
|1  |A      |HR  |F   |6        |
|1  |A      |HR  |P   |5        |
|1  |A      |HR  |M   |7        |
+---+-------+----+----+---------+
```

Code:

```
df_res = spark.sql("""
  select ID, COMPANY, DEPT, FLAG, INDICATOR, last(ind_value, True ) over (partition by ID, COMPANY, DEPT 
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
  as c1
  from  (
   select *, 
   case when FLAG = 'F' then INDICATOR end as ind_value
   from data_table ) a

""")

df_res.show(20,False)
```

Output:

```
+---+-------+----+----+---------+---+
|ID |COMPANY|DEPT|FLAG|INDICATOR|c1 |
+---+-------+----+----+---------+---+
|1  |A      |HR  |F   |3        |3  |
|1  |A      |HR  |P   |2        |3  |
|1  |A      |HR  |M   |4        |3  |
|1  |A      |HR  |F   |6        |6  |
|1  |A      |HR  |P   |5        |6  |
|1  |A      |HR  |M   |7        |6  |
+---+-------+----+----+---------+---+
```

Comment: Hi @pcbzmani, Great, this is also working fine, Many thanks..It should also work if we pass multiple Flags in the CASE statement... correct? Plz answer!

Comment: Hi @Johnson , Multiple Flag means, then we have multiple indicator ? Can you put some specific example to understand it better.

Comment: Hi @pcbzmani, like if we change the CASE as ```CASE WHEN FLAG IN ('F', 'P') THEN INDICATOR END AS IND_VALUE```... It will also work , correct?

Comment: Yes, it will work.